# Rabbit Mq Not Consuming Messages after first message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

After posting message in queue, receiveing same message twice at the lisitener side.
After receving the first message listner stops consuming furthe message . After i restart the listener application it picks the pending message in queue with duplicates.Also receving exception as .Same config is working with other queues

```
 SimpleMessageListenerContainer.run: 1251 | Consumer thread error, thread abort.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/MethodArgumentResolutionException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy.isCauseFatal(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:182)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy.isFatal(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:104)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1383)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1667)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:958)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:908)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) 

>SimpleMessageListenerContainer.killOrRestart: 1398 | Stopping container from aborted consumer
> Dpendency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/MethodArgumentResolutionException

You seem to be missing `spring-messaging` from the class path (or a version that is incompatible, or the jar is corrupt somehow).

Show your versions/dependencies.

Comment: added the depedency  . Same its working for other 2 queues

Comment: `<version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>` is too old; since you are using Spring Boot, you should omit the version and let Boot bring in the right compatible version. But you didn't show which version of Boot you are using.

Comment: We use  spring boot version  2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Boot 2.2.x has not been supported for a long time now. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support